Unable to validate Azure Event Grid (using Event Grid Scheme) subscription using python
I need help. I've been trying to get an Webhook validation from Azure Event Grid events. My code returns the following error:
POST / HTTP/1.1 405  (Method Not Allowed)
Deploying Event Subscription: XXXXX
Deployment has failed with the following error:
{"code":"URL validation", "message":"Webhook validation
handshake failed for https://XXXXX.ngrok.app/.
Http POST request failed with response code Unknown.
For troubleshooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation.
Im following the instructions set on https://aka.ms/esvalidation. I can't see why the validation fails:
Here is my python code:
# Define the webhook route    
webhook_blueprint = Blueprint('webhook', __name__)

# Define the webhook route
@webhook_blueprint.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    from pprint import pprint
    try:
        # Get headers and data
        headers = request.headers
        data = request.get_json()
        
        # Log incoming request
        pprint(f"Incoming webhook headers: {headers}")
        pprint(f"Incoming webhook data: {data}")

        # Check if this is a validation request
        if headers.get('aeg-event-type') == 'SubscriptionValidation':
            pprint("Received subscription validation request")
            
            # Process the validation event
            for event in data:
                if event['eventType'] == 'Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent':
                    validation_code = event['data']['validationCode']
                    pprint(f"Returning validation code: {validation_code}")
                    
                    # Return the validation response
                    return jsonify({
                        "validationResponse": validation_code
                    })

        # Handle your original webhook logic for non-validation requests
        pprint("Processing regular webhook request")

        
        #TODO: Write Webhook routing
        pprint(f"Processing webhook data: {data}")
        
        return jsonify({'status': 'success'}), 200

and here's my CORS setup:
# Configure CORS specifically for the webhook blueprint
CORS(webhook_blueprint, 
     origins="*",
    methods=['POST'],
    supports_credentials=False)


I eventually fixed it for python. The issue was due to a small typo. In the example, C# users upper caps for the variables. The validation actually receives is as lowercapUppercap (eg: validationResponse), while the C# example uses UppercapUpperCap.  Also, with python, jsonify({
"validationResponse": validation_code
}) is sufficient enough. There's no need to add extra "200" (despite the documentation suggesting for so).

I tried your code with the same URL but encountered the same error. This error occurs because the POST request requires data in the JSON format in the body
curl -X POST https://AzureWebName.azurewebsites.net/webhook \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent", "data": {"validationCode": "123456"}}'


I added a GET method to the endpoint to check the response of get :
@webhook_blueprint.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

Additionally, Using this Azure CLI documentation link, you can enable webhooks in Azure Container Registry  with a URL to list recent events for a webhook.
 az acr webhook create -n mywebhook3 -r sampath6778566 --uri  https://AzureWebname.azurewebsites
.net/webhook --actions push delete


To list recent webhook events:
az acr webhook list-events -n mywebhook -r myregistry



